# Error creating binary file: "UnsatisfiedLinkError ibm/jzos/ZFile.fopen" after springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean trigger

Tags: java, unix, websphere, quartz-scheduler, zos

The scenario:
MyApp runs on Unix (mainframe z/390). There is certainly scheduller to evoke the read method and then the write_binary_file method. All things go fine untill I have to deploy the appliation. Sometimes, when I stop the application and deploy a new version  I get the error showed below. Then I have to restart maybe once, wait to see if it will fix, maybe not, than other restart and see again if it will fix the error. The code where the error rases is the same for at least 2 years. I am fixing the error only by re-starting and waiting to check. I believe the maximum restart number was three.
I am not using maven so all jars are listed below.

The exception:
It happens while trying to create a binary file. The must correct name would be PDS (PDS is type of file in mainframe world). If it happens once after I deployed, it will not be fixed untill I restart the server node in Websphere. Only restarting MyApp as webapplication will not fix the issue as well.

My question:
Has someone faced similiar issue with ibm.jzos.ZFile or springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean? Could it be related to class loader, ibmjzos.jar, jzos.jar, quartz-1.6.0.jar or quartz-all-1.6.0.jar? If so, what I have to check? It is hard to narrow the error since it keeps to work perfectly and it will not crash until I re-deploy the application. I hard can think it is an issue with quartz since I am using quartz for other tasks and they work correctly while the write_binary_file fails.

The exception from Websphere 7 running with Java 7:

```
Exception in thread "Writing Dataset" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/ibm/jisfiedLinkError: com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.fopen(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)

0 at com.ibm.jzos.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:289)

0 at myApp.write_binary_file

…

0 at myApp.scheduling.DatasetNotificationTask$1.run(DatasetNotificationTask.java:
```

The exact place where the error happens:

```
/**
       * Write a byte array to the given file. Writing binary data is
       * significantly simpler than reading it.
       */

       void write_binary_file (byte[] aInput, String aOutputFileName) {

              try {

                     ZFile zFile = new ZFile(aOutputFileName, FILE_OPTIONS); //*** the error raises here ***

                     OutputStream output = null;

                     ArrayList<byte[]> noOfRecords = getNoOfRecords(aInput);

                     try {

                           output = zFile.getOutputStream();

                           int totalBytesWritten = 0;

                           for (int i = 0; i < noOfRecords.size(); i++) {

                                  byte[] record = noOfRecords.get(i);

                                  totalBytesWritten = totalBytesWritten + record.length;

                                  output.write(record);

                           }

System.out.println("Total bytes written : " + totalBytesWritten);

                     } finally {

                           output.close();

                     }

              } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

                     System.out.println("File not found.");

              } catch (IOException ex) {

                     System.out.println(ex);

                     ex.printStackTrace();

              }

       }
```

There is no error in this method but I placed here for help to give a context idea

byte[] read(String aInputFileName) {

```
      File file = new File(aInputFileName);

      byte[] result = new byte[(int) file.length()];

      try {

             InputStream input = null;

             try {

                   int totalBytesRead = 0;

                   input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

                   while (totalBytesRead < result.length) {

                          int bytesRemaining = result.length - totalBytesRead;

                          int bytesRead = input.read(result, totalBytesRead,

                                        bytesRemaining);

                          if (bytesRead > 0) {

                                 totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

                          }

                   }

                   /*

                   * the above style is a bit tricky: it places bytes into the

                   * 'result' array; 'result' is an output parameter; the while

                   * loop usually has a single iteration only.

                   */

                   System.out.println("Num bytes read: " + totalBytesRead);

             } finally {

                   input.close();

             }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

             System.out.println("File not found.");

      } catch (IOException ex) {

             System.out.println(ex);

             ex.printStackTrace();

      }

      return result;
```

}

myApp-servelt (the only important part)

```
       <bean id="datasetNotifyerCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

                <property name="jobDetail" ref="datasetNotifyerJobDetail"/>

                <property name="cronExpression" value="45 0/5 * * * ?"/>

       </bean>



       <bean id="quartzScheduleFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

       <property name="triggers">

              <list>

...

            <ref bean="datasetNotifyerCronTrigger" />                                    

              </list>

       </property>

       </bean>
```

All libs beyond Java 7

"activation.jar" "classes12.jar" "commons-collections.jar" "commons-fileupload.jar" "commons-io-1.4.jar" "commons-logging.jar" "ibmjzos.jar" "javax.jar" "jstl.jar" "jta.jar" "jzos.jar" "log4j-1.2.14.jar" "mail.jar" "quartz-1.6.0.jar" "quartz-all-1.6.0.jar" "spring.jar" "standard.jar" "xalan-2.4.1.jar" "xerces-1.4.4.jar"

******* Edited in 2016/March/18 at 5PM Brazilia timezone

The deployment process is exactly two steps:

First Step:

```
BPXBATCH SH /WebSphere/was7/mycell/wmbdmgrn/DeploymentManager/profiles/default/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /DEPLOY.jy
```

DEPLOY.jy

```
import sys
APP_NAME = "MTF-myApp"
NODE = "wmbmyAppa"

AdminApp.uninstall(APP_NAME)
AdminConfig.save()

nodelist = AdminConfig.list('Node').splitlines()
for node in nodelist:
  nodename = AdminConfig.showAttribute(node, 'name')
  if nodename != NODE:
    continue
  else:
    objn = "type=NodeSync,node=" + nodename + ",*"
    Syncl = AdminControl.completeObjectName(objn)
    AdminControl.invoke(Syncl, 'sync')
    print ASTER + " Node " + nodename + " is now Syncronized"
    continue

EARFILE = "/WebSphere/MCA/myApp/mtf/curr/warfiles/myAppEAR.ear"

APPOPTS = " -nopreCompileJSPs "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-installed.ear.destination "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "/WebSphere/MCA/myApp/mtf/curr/deployment/ "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-distributeApp "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-nouseMetaDataFromBinary "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-nodeployejb "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-appname MTF-myApp "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-createMBeansForResources "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-noreloadEnabled "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-nodeployws "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-validateinstall warn "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-processEmbeddedConfig "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-filepermission "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + ".*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-noallowDispatchRemoteInclude "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-noallowServiceRemoteInclude "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-nouseAutoLink "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-contextroot / "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "-MapModulesToServers "
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "[[ myApp myApp.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:"
APPOPTS = APPOPTS + "cell=mtfcell,node=wmbmyAppa,server=WMBmyApp ]] "

AdminApp.install(EARFILE, APPOPTS)
AdminConfig.save()

nodelist = AdminConfig.list('Node').splitlines()
for node in nodelist:
  nodename = AdminConfig.showAttribute(node, 'name')
  if nodename != NODE:
    continue
  else:
    objn = "type=NodeSync,node=" + nodename + ",*"
    Syncl = AdminControl.completeObjectName(objn)
    AdminControl.invoke(Syncl, 'sync')
    continue
```

Second step:

```
BPXBATCH SH /WebSphere/was7/mtfcell/wmbdmgrn/DeploymentManager/profiles/default/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /ALTER.jy
```

ALTER.jy

```
import sys

APP_NAME = "MTF-myApp"
NODE = "wmbmyAppa"

deploymentlist = AdminConfig.list('Deployment').splitlines()
for deployment in deploymentlist:
    depappname = deployment.split('(')[0]
    if (depappname.startswith('"')):
        depappname = depappname[1:]
    if depappname == APP_NAME:
        deploymentid = deployment
        break
    continue
loadermodeattr = ["classloaderMode", "PARENT_LAST"]
appdeploy = AdminConfig.showAttribute(deploymentid, "deployedObject")
modules = AdminConfig.showAttribute(appdeploy, "modules").splitlines()
for module in modules:
    if module.startswith('["') and module.endswith('"]'):
        module = module[2:-2]
    elif module.startswith('[') and module.endswith(']'):
        module = module[1:-1]
    AdminConfig.modify(module, [loadermodeattr])
    print ASTER, APP_NAME, " changed to classloader PARENT LAST"
    continue
AdminConfig.save()

nodelist = AdminConfig.list('Node').splitlines()
for node in nodelist:
  nodename = AdminConfig.showAttribute(node, 'name')
  if nodename != NODE:
    continue
  else:
    objn = "type=NodeSync,node=" + nodename + ",*"
    Syncl = AdminControl.completeObjectName(objn)
    AdminControl.invoke(Syncl, 'sync')

    continue
```

Answer (score 3):

It is having trouble finding either lib/s390/libjzos.so or lib/s390x/libjzos.so (depending on whether you are in 31 or 64 bit).  I don't know why restarting the server would sometimes fix that though.  There are often layers of symlinks between where LIBPATH points and where the files actually are.  Perhaps something in there resolves differently on a restart?  Perhaps something is different in how the server starts normally vs. restarts (e.g. via automation vs. through the admin console?).

Comment: Please, can you look at the deployment procedure I am using and tell me anything you think it is not a good pratice or could be causing the issue I got? When I restart the server I do throw Admin Console and usually it fix the issue but, to deploy the application, I am always following the two above steps.

Comment: DFollis, here is 64 bits. I looked in three places. There are several libXXXX.so but I didn't find libjzos.so (the last two are symbolic ones)

Connection Central\Secure FTP - MYSERVER\$HNFTP_HFS\WebSphere\was7\mtfcell\wmbMyAppa\AppServer\lib (the server)

Connection Central\Secure FTP - MYSERVER\$HNFTP_HFS\WebSphere\was7\mtfcell\wmbMyAppa\MTFCELL.WMBMYAPPA.WMBMYAPP.HOME\lib (the web application)

Connection Central\Secure FTP - MYSERVER\$HNFTP_HFS\WebSphere\was7\mtfcell\wmbMyAppa\MTFCELL.WMBMYAPPA.WMBMYAPPA.HOME\lib (certain agent)

Should I look for libjzos.so in other directory?

Comment: Kindly, if you look at the jars I am using you will see ibmjzos.jar and jzos.jar. I guess the one you told, libjzos.so, is the same of one of these two, right?

Comment: Hi all, I am carefully looking at this question often.